# Protractor: Only Chrome is run

Tags: macos, protractor, selenium-firefoxdriver

My Protractor config contains the following:

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 111000,
  directConnect: false,  //also tried directConnect: true

  specs: [
    './e2e/spec/**/*-spec.ts'
  ],

  suites: {
    basic: [
      './e2e/spec/**/widths-spec.ts'
    ],
    all: [
        './e2e/spec/**/*-spec.ts'
    ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    //'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
//snipet cut...
```

If I comment out the chrome capability line as shown above, firefox does not get run - chrome still runs.  There are no errors produced and the tests execute without problems (except they're not run in firefox).  I'm running with a script: `$ npm run e2e:local:auto -- --suite basic` and just updated FireFox to the latest version (v.65.0) and running on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: change `directConnect` to `true` and try to run

Comment: I've tried that and it had no effect; still Chrome runs.

Comment: Do you know if geckodriver was downloaded?

Comment: Yes, geckodriver was downloaded.

Comment: Are you launching the webdriver server locally and connecting on the default port? If so are you passing any parameters when launching it or simply using 'webdriver-manager start'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following config for the firefox browser:

```
   capabilities: {
     browserName: 'firefox',
     marionette: true,
     acceptInsecureCerts: true,
     'moz:firefoxOptions': {
       args: ['--headless'], // this one is only for headless mode
     },
   }
```

Comment: Tried as suggested.  Still runs Chrome!  I also made sure that multiCapabilities is commented out as that would override the capabilities section.

Comment: I haven't resolved this yet, but I suspect the issue is related to:  [1]:  https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/269#issuecomment-366819957